# Invoking HTTPS webservice from flex

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, https

I have an https .net webservice. Invoking web methods using tools like soap UI works fine. I am unable to invoke the webmethod from flex. My WSDL loads up fine in flex.

On deployment my flex application and the webservice are on the same server. When use the machine url and access from within the server it works fine, but not when I use the https url for the flex application.

Eg - http://machinename/flex/flexApp.html works fine with https://publicname/wservice/ws.asmx but https://publicname/flex/flexapp.html fails to work.

I have the crossdomain policy in place with full access and also I have a valid SSL certificate on the server.

When I make the call from my local machine in debug mode I see the following in Fiddler-

The WSDL call goes fine and returns back correctly and the Protocol is shown as HTTPS where as the webmethod call following it shows the protocol as HTTP and returns back with the error -
I have been stuck on this for quite some time. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Nikhil.

Here is my Flex code that calls it:

```
//business delegate

public function BusinessDelegate(responder : IResponder):void
    {
        _responder = responder;
        _service = ServiceLocator.getInstance().getService("sqlWebService");
        _service.loadWSDL();
    }

    //Login User
    public function Login(userId:String,password:String):void
    {
        var asyncToken:AsyncToken = _service.LoginUser(userId,password);
        asyncToken.addResponder(_responder);
    }
```

and the service locator has the following tag where I set the URL from outside as https://....

```
<mx:WebService 
    id="sqlWebService" 
    useProxy="false" 
    concurrency="multiple"
    showBusyCursor="true"
    wsdl="{Url}"/>
```

Comment: Are you the web service and the Flex app served from the same domain?  Beyond that, I think you'll have to show some code, and a description of the errors you're receiving.  Perhaps your crossdomain.xml file.  Perhaps the Flex code that calls your service.  Are you sure you are specifying HTTPS in the Flex WebSrvice call?

Comment: Your last point..This is what I feel is going wrong, when I see that in fiddler the WSDL get call shows protocol as HTTPS where as when the webmethod is invoked it shows protocol as HTTP which seems to fail and returns with 502 error. What code should I be writing to ensure the call goes out as HTTPS and not HTTP?

Comment: Usually you just specify an HTTPS value as part of the WebService (or HTTPService) class.  Show us the code that calls the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to resolve this problem by replacing the code where I call the Flex WebService object with the specific generated classes for the webservice.

I generated classes for the webservice using Import WebService(WSDL) and was setting the url on the main class on run time as https://.....

and it works like a charm...and I see that in fiddler it shows me correctly going out as HTTPS instead of the HTTP.

Here is what helped me -
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=security2_15.html
Comment by nated.

Thanks Flextras.com for pointing me to right direction.
Resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If using WCF service and WebService in Flex, use 
service.svc?wsdl for HTTP and 
service.svc/wsdl?wsdl for HTTPS,